# R using function "aggr" of VIM's package with title

Tags: r, title

I'm trying to use the function `aggr(df)` of `VIM`'s package in R.
My problem is that there is no way to get a title in the graphical plot.
My coding is the following:

```
aggr(df,combined = TRUE, numbers=TRUE, cex.numbers=0.5)
```

[image: plot of the aggr-function]

The function `aggr` does not have a attribute like `main = "Bla"` or `title="Bla"`. That's why I tried to do the following:

```
 plot(df, aggr(df, combined = TRUE, numbers = TRUE, cex.numbers = 0.5), main = "Caption")
```

or

```
 plot(df, aggr(df, combined = TRUE, numbers = TRUE, cex.numbers = 0.5), title = "Caption")
```

My output changes now. Now it has a caption, but i want the first picture with a title.

Now the output looks like this:

[image: using plot function around VIM's package aggr function]

Answer (score 1):

`aggr` uses R's built in graphics package, so you can use its `title` function to supply a title.

```
aggr(...)
title(main = "Missingness Plots")
```